# Paypal subscribe button security

Tags: paypal

As I read the docs on Paypal's subscribe button, I get more and more worried about security. Supplying the dollar amount as a hidden input seems pretty easy to modify with firebug and change to something different. How does Paypal verify the dollar amount or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can verify the amount received using paypals IPN, when the payment goes through it will notify your script of the payment, then have your script check the amount received, if its different that what it should be then flag it.